# Add menu options to Floating Action Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button

I am looking for adding menu items for the floating action buttons (FAB) in android application.

Means, when i click the FAB i want actions like "Save", "Save & Add New", "Go Back" etc.

As I am pretty new to the development, I couldn't try much of experimentation on this

Somehow unable to get this going... currently i have the default button which when clicked shows the snack bar suggesting me to have my own icon.

please help, thanks.

Lakshman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **FloatingActionMenu** for achieving such functionality. You can take a look at [this project on Github by Clans.](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

Comment: with due respect to the github project shared want to know if  i can do this with android default functionality without using any 3rd party.

Comment: You can study the implementation on that project. Surely you should create a custom fab.